# Add-AzureAccount : The cache contains multiple tokens satisfying the requirements

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to [install and configure Azure PowerShell](http://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/).

I've successfully installed Azure PS and when I run `Add-AzureAccount` and login with my valid credentials I am shown this error message:

> Add-AzureAccount : The cache contains multiple tokens satisfying the
>   requirements. Call  AcquireToken again providing more requirements
>   (e.g. UserId)

How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get-azureaccount will show you all the accounts in your current powershell session.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495234.aspx

remove-azureaccount will prompt you to enter the name of the account you want to remove.  Enter the emailaddress (name) you want removed and it will remove it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn722529.aspx